# How many integers have no prime factor bigger than their own square root?

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Two questions:

- Is there a name for integers $n$ having no prime factors exceeding $\sqrt n$?
- What results say something about the frequency with which these occur? For example, if $A$ is the set of such numbers, then might $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap\{1,\ldots,n\}|} n$ exist? Or liminf and limsup? Or maybe $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap\{1,\ldots,n\}|} n g(n)$ exists for some specified function $g$? Etc. (A few not-really-random samples of numbers less than $10^5$ suggest maybe a bit more than a quarter of those are in $A$.)

Comment: This : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatestPrimeFactor.html should be helpful

Comment: @Peter : Thank you.  The number $1-\log 2 \approx0.31$ is "a bit more than a quarter", roughly.

Comment: A moment, you search $\sqrt{n}$-smooth numbers, not $\sqrt{n}$-rough-numbers, right ? There is no asymptotic density given for those numbers.

Comment: Yes. MathWorld is reporting around $1 - 0.73$ for what I called "a bit more than a quarter."

Comment: Where did I find what? The MathWorld article? You linked to it.

Comment: Where did you find the number $0.73$ ?

Comment: In the graph on the MathWorld page.

Comment: How could I overlook this ? Is this helpful for your question ?

Comment: Maybe..... I will ponder this.

Comment: See [Dickman's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function)

Comment: If $p_{\omega(n)}$ is the greatest prime factor of $n$, do you require $\sqrt n > p_{\omega(n)}$, or do you allow $\sqrt n \geq p_{\omega(n)}$?

Comment: @RobertSoupe : $\sqrt n \ge p$ is enough to mean that $n$ has no "large" prime factors. A "large" prime factor is one that is strictly bigger than the product of all the others. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Alright, so squares of primes would be in this sequence, adjusting my OEIS search...

Comment: The OEIS calls them "$\sqrt n$-smooth numbers," like @Peter said a few comments ago: http://oeis.org/A048098 There's some talk there of density but not frequency. I haven't looked at the linked Davenport and Erdős paper yet.